# Selectively zero weights in TensorFlow?

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Lets say I have an NxM weight variable `weights` and a constant NxM matrix of 1s and 0s `mask`.

If a layer of my network is defined like this (with other layers similarly defined):

```
masked_weights = mask*weights
layer1 = tf.relu(tf.matmul(layer0, masked_weights) + biases1)
```

Will this network behave as if the corresponding 0s in `mask` are zeros in `weights` during training? (i.e. as if the connections represented by those weights had been removed from the network entirely)?

If not, how can I achieve this goal in TensorFlow?

Comment: This will work yes, the zeroed weights will not receive any gradient, and the other will receive normal gradient

Answer (score 4):

The answer is yes. The experiment depicts the following graph.[image]

The implementation is:

```
import numpy as np, scipy as sp, tensorflow as tf

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 3))
weights = tf.get_variable("weights", [3, 2])
bias = tf.get_variable("bias", [2])
mask = tf.constant(np.asarray([[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=np.float32)) # constant mask

masked_weights = tf.multiply(weights, mask)
y = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.bias_add(tf.matmul(x, masked_weights), bias))
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(tf.constant(np.asarray([[1, 1]], dtype=np.float32)),y)

weights_grad = tf.gradients(loss, weights)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print("Masked weights=\n", sess.run(masked_weights))
data = np.random.rand(1, 3)

print("Graident of weights\n=", sess.run(weights_grad, feed_dict={x: data}))
sess.close()
```

After running the code above, you will see the gradients are masked as well. In my example, they are:

```
Graident of weights
= [array([[ 0.        , -0.40866762],
       [ 0.34265977, -0.        ],
       [ 0.        , -0.35294518]], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very simplistic but yet informative and illustrative example! Helped me a lot!

Comment: After many hours looking for this, this solution worked for me. Thank you so much! Just a note for others, multiply the weights by the mask both during `build()` and `call()`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes and the reason lies in backpropogation as explained below.

`mask_w = mask * w`

`del(mask_w) = mask * del(w)`.

The mask will make the gradient 0 wherever its value is zero. Wherever its value is 1, gradient will flow as previously. This is a common trick used in seq2seq predictions to mask the different size output in decoding layer. You can read more about this [here](https://r2rt.com/recurrent-neural-networks-in-tensorflow-iii-variable-length-sequences.html).